# more normal baking problems

Tags: normals, baking

Im trying to bake a high poly sculpted model to a low poly plain model with out any modifiers to produce my normal map.
my procedure is this- after sculpting a multires model, I copy the model and remove the multires modifier from the copy. Then I place the two models over one another and select both models making sure the low poly is the active model i proceed to bake using the setting shown in attached picture.
 I have done it this way multiple times before, the last time i did this was 2-3 day ago so i know it was working and now for some reason it give me the error as shown in attached picture. Does anyone know where i went wrong? I'm using version 2.74 which i re-downloaded today just incase it was the version giving me the problem[image]

Comment: I am having this problem when the low poly model does not have created map. Select your low poly model, select all faces, got to UV editor and click on bottom of screen to "+ NEW" and create new image. Then continue with standard procedure (select high poly, select low poly, bake)

Comment: That error you are seeing is a nuisance.  It could be that you did not have every face selected when you applied the texture, however, it is also a known and difficult to reproduce bug.  I once found some advice somewhere on the BF website that says to select everything and then reassign the texture and then enter Object mode before re-attempting the bake.  Sometimes that will fix it but not always.  It's really hard to reproduce and because of this, the cause is very difficult to track down and fix.  (continued...)

Comment: It's never happened to me with Cycles Texture Baking so you may want to learn both methods so you have a fallback if one or the other fails.  If you want, you can upload the model to PasteAll.org and paste the link here.  I will have a look at it.